# Push free/busy status from Outlook.com to Exchange/Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I would like to keep my personal calendar on Outlook.com. My work calendar is in Exchange, accessed with the Outlook client.

Is there a way to push the free/busy status from my Outlook.com calendar in to Exchange? If I have a personal appointment, I don't want someone scheduling a work meeting. Conversely, I don't want to store my personal appointments on a work owned calendar.

This has to be a common question!

Comment: Common enough to have a Possible Duplicate: [How to (one way) sync calendars between 'work' email account (exchange) and outlook.com\hotmail.com](http://superuser.com/questions/539778/how-to-one-way-sync-calendars-between-work-email-account-exchange-and-outl?rq=1) :)

Comment: techie007, wrong direction. I want to go Outlook.com to Exchange. That question wants to go work->personal which makes it a security concern. My question should have no security concerns since I just want it to block off personal times.